# Does the number of tasks, stages and jobs vary when executing a Spark application under the same configuration?

Tags: apache-spark, k-means, apache-spark-ml

I'm currently executing the K-Means algorithm in a cluster.

Between to consecutive executions under the same configuration (same number of executors, RAM, iterations, dataset) the number of tasks, jobs and stages can vary quite a lot. Over 10 executions the number of tasks reached a standard deviation of about 500 tasks.

Is this normal? Shouldn't the DAG be the same under the same configurations?

I'm running the Spark implementing of K-Means using Scala.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's perfectly normal behavior.

The number of iterations required for K-Means to converge depends on the initial choice of centroids, and the process is either fully (random init mode) or partially (K-Means|| init mode) random.

Since each iteration triggers a job (and creates a separate DAG), number of stages, and consequently tasks, is proportional to the number of iterations performed before satisfying convergence criteria.

Comment: Thank you. I just read the documentation carefully and saw that the number of iterations is in fact the maximum number of iterations, so in some cases the algorithm is probably achieving convergence early on, resulting in less tasks.